# How to download specific item from FireBase, but not all list with items?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get specific item from my FireBase DB, for example I have Array with cars in my FireBase and each car have a unique ID I want to download just one specific car searched by ID and I want to parse it to Car java object without downloading all unnecessary list of cars.

Comment: what about `equalTo()`? from `firebase` documentation, you can find more info [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html)

Comment: you helped me thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to specific list of objects which you want to search using `.child("cars")`, after that get specific element you want to campare in this example is carId, `.orderByChild("carId")` and finaly check if its value equals to your `.equalTo("2")`. The final result is `fireBaseRef.child("cars").orderByChild("carId").equalTo("2");` this will return all cars with id of 2. If you know better way please write here :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to your self-answer is to store the cars under their id:

```
cars
  car_1
    make: ...
    model: ...
  car_2
    make: ...
    model: ...
```

Then you can access the cars without needing a query, which means things will scale a lot better:

```
var id = 2;
ref.child('cars').child('car_'+id)...
```

Note that it is considered a bad practice to store array indices as keys in Firebase, which is why I prefixed the ids with `car_`.